# Printing out a specific part of text from requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I've been trying to scrape out data from a profile to have a set of information whether something changed, here's a snippet of what overall code would probably would look like:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://twitter.com/elonmusk')

print(response.text[30907:30957])

#need to print out "sensitive_media_settings_enabled":{"value":false}
```

I need to have "sensitive_media_settings_enabled":{"value":false} printed out in the shell, how can I do this?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Btw that's probably not reliable as the length of the response can always change and that line might go somewhere else. You could regex for `"sensitive_media_settings_enabled":{"value":false}|"sensitive_media_settings_enabled":{"value":true}}` instead.

Comment: I need to have "sensitive_media_settings_enabled":{"value":false} printed out in the shell Matt, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Like Ali said in a comment, a better approach to this is to use a regular expression to find and extract the string you're looking for. When I tried this, the index start and stop were at 43539 and 43589 respectively.

Here's how you could do it with regex

```py
import re
import requests

response = requests.get('https://twitter.com/elonmusk')
reg_expression = r'"sensitive_media_settings_enabled":{"value":(true|false)}'
result = re.search(reg_expression, response.text)

print(result[0])
```

prints `"sensitive_media_settings_enabled":{"value":false}`